# Passing Function between components Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm currently trying to pass the `getUser` function from a file called `Login.vue` which gets the login details to an `Authenticated.vue` page to display the user and their email. How can I go about doing this. I've tried following the official vue documents but can't get it to work. Not sure whats going wrong.

Login.Vue

```
<template>
<form @submit.prevent="submitLogin">
        <div>
            <!-- Email -->
            <div>
                <label for="email" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">
                    Email
                </label>
                <input v-model="loginForm.email" id="email" type="email" class="block mt-1 w-full rounded-md shadow-sm border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50" required autofocus autocomplete="username">
                <!-- Validation Errors -->
                <div class="text-red-600 mt-1">
                    <div v-for="message in validationErrors?.email">
                        {{ message }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Password -->
            <div class="mt-4">
                <label for="password" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">
                    Password
                </label>
                <input v-model="loginForm.password" id="password" type="password" class="block mt-1 w-full rounded-md shadow-sm border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50" required autocomplete="current-password">
                <!-- Validation Errors -->
                <div class="text-red-600 mt-1">
                    <div v-for="message in validationErrors?.password">
                        {{ message }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Remember me -->
            <div class="block mt-4">
                <label class="flex items-center">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" v-model="loginForm.remember" class="rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50" />
                    <span class="ml-2 text-sm text-gray-600">Remember me</span>
                </label>
            </div>

            <!-- Buttons -->
            <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
                <button class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-900 focus:shadow-outline-gray transition ease-in-out duration-150 ml-4" :class="{ 'opacity-25': processing }" :disabled="processing">
                    Log in
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
import { useRouter} from 'vue-router';
import { reactive } from '@vue/runtime-core'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            categories: {},
            router: useRouter(),
            loginForm: reactive({
                email: '',
                password: '',
                remember: false
            }),
            user: reactive({
                name: '',
                email: '',
            }),
            processing: false,
            validationErrors: {},

        }
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    methods: {
        submitLogin() {

            if (this.processing) return

            this.processing = true;

            axios.post('/login', this.loginForm)
            .then(response => this.loginUser(response))
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response?.data) {
                    this.validationErrors = error.response.data.errors
                }
            })
            .finally(this.processing = false)
        },
        loginUser(response){
            this.user.name = response.data.name
            this.user.email = response.data.email
            localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', JSON.stringify(true))
            this.router.push({name: 'posts.index'})
        },
        getUser(){
            axios.get('/api/user')
            .then(response => {
                loginUser(response)
            })
            this.user.name = response.data.name
            this.user.email = response.data.email
            console.log(this.user.name);
            console.log(this.user.email);
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Authenticated.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
        <nav class="bg-white border-b border-gray-100">
            <!-- Primary Navigation Menu -->
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="flex justify-between h-16">
                    <div class="flex">
                        <!-- Logo -->
                        <div class="shrink-0 flex items-center">
                            <a href="/">
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 316 316" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="block h-10 w-auto fill-current text-gray-600">
                                    <path d="M305.8 81.125C305.77 80.995 305.69 80.885 305.65 80.755C305.56 80.525 305.49 80.285 305.37 80.075C305.29 79.935 305.17 79.815 305.07 79.685C304.94 79.515 304.83 79.325 304.68 79.175C304.55 79.045 304.39 78.955 304.25 78.845C304.09 78.715 303.95 78.575 303.77 78.475L251.32 48.275C249.97 47.495 248.31 47.495 246.96 48.275L194.51 78.475C194.33 78.575 194.19 78.725 194.03 78.845C193.89 78.955 193.73 79.045 193.6 79.175C193.45 79.325 193.34 79.515 193.21 79.685C193.11 79.815 192.99 79.935 192.91 80.075C192.79 80.285 192.71 80.525 192.63 80.755C192.58 80.875 192.51 80.995 192.48 81.125C192.38 81.495 192.33 81.875 192.33 82.265V139.625L148.62 164.795V52.575C148.62 52.185 148.57 51.805 148.47 51.435C148.44 51.305 148.36 51.195 148.32 51.065C148.23 50.835 148.16 50.595 148.04 50.385C147.96 50.245 147.84 50.125 147.74 49.995C147.61 49.825 147.5 49.635 147.35 49.485C147.22 49.355 147.06 49.265 146.92 49.155C146.76 49.025 146.62 48.885 146.44 48.785L93.99 18.585C92.64 17.805 90.98 17.805 89.63 18.585L37.18 48.785C37 48.885 36.86 49.035 36.7 49.155C36.56 49.265 36.4 49.355 36.27 49.485C36.12 49.635 36.01 49.825 35.88 49.995C35.78 50.125 35.66 50.245 35.58 50.385C35.46 50.595 35.38 50.835 35.3 51.065C35.25 51.185 35.18 51.305 35.15 51.435C35.05 51.805 35 52.185 35 52.575V232.235C35 233.795 35.84 235.245 37.19 236.025L142.1 296.425C142.33 296.555 142.58 296.635 142.82 296.725C142.93 296.765 143.04 296.835 143.16 296.865C143.53 296.965 143.9 297.015 144.28 297.015C144.66 297.015 145.03 296.965 145.4 296.865C145.5 296.835 145.59 296.775 145.69 296.745C145.95 296.655 146.21 296.565 146.45 296.435L251.36 236.035C252.72 235.255 253.55 233.815 253.55 232.245V174.885L303.81 145.945C305.17 145.165 306 143.725 306 142.155V82.265C305.95 81.875 305.89 81.495 305.8 81.125ZM144.2 227.205L100.57 202.515L146.39 176.135L196.66 147.195L240.33 172.335L208.29 190.625L144.2 227.205ZM244.75 114.995V164.795L226.39 154.225L201.03 139.625V89.825L219.39 100.395L244.75 114.995ZM249.12 57.105L292.81 82.265L249.12 107.425L205.43 82.265L249.12 57.105ZM114.49 184.425L96.13 194.995V85.305L121.49 70.705L139.85 60.135V169.815L114.49 184.425ZM91.76 27.425L135.45 52.585L91.76 77.745L48.07 52.585L91.76 27.425ZM43.67 60.135L62.03 70.705L87.39 85.305V202.545V202.555V202.565C87.39 202.735 87.44 202.895 87.46 203.055C87.49 203.265 87.49 203.485 87.55 203.695V203.705C87.6 203.875 87.69 204.035 87.76 204.195C87.84 204.375 87.89 204.575 87.99 204.745C87.99 204.745 87.99 204.755 88 204.755C88.09 204.905 88.22 205.035 88.33 205.175C88.45 205.335 88.55 205.495 88.69 205.635L88.7 205.645C88.82 205.765 88.98 205.855 89.12 205.965C89.28 206.085 89.42 206.225 89.59 206.325C89.6 206.325 89.6 206.325 89.61 206.335C89.62 206.335 89.62 206.345 89.63 206.345L139.87 234.775V285.065L43.67 229.705V60.135ZM244.75 229.705L148.58 285.075V234.775L219.8 194.115L244.75 179.875V229.705ZM297.2 139.625L253.49 164.795V114.995L278.85 100.395L297.21 89.825V139.625H297.2Z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Navigation Links -->
                        <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                            <router-link :to="{name:'posts.index'}" active-class="border-b-2 border-indigo-400" class="inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                                Posts
                            </router-link>
                            <router-link :to="{name:'posts.create'}" active-class="border-b-2 border-indigo-400" class="inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                                Create Post
                            </router-link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex items-center">
                        <div>
                            <div>Hi, {{user.name}}</div>
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-500"> {{user.email}} </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button @click="logout" type="button" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-900 focus:shadow-outline-gray transition ease-in-out duration-150 ml-4" :class="{ 'opacity-25': processing }" :disabled="processing">
                        Log out
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- Page Heading -->
        <header class="bg-white shadow">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                    {{currentPageTitle}}
                </h2>
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <main>
            <div class="py-12">
                <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                    <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                        <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                            <router-view></router-view>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive } from '@vue/runtime-core'
export default {
    props: {
        getUser: {type: Function}
    },
    computed: {
        currentPageTitle(){
            return this.$route.meta.title;
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getUser()
    },
    methods: {
    }
}
</script>
```

App.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp, onMounted } from 'vue'
//import App from './layouts/App'
import LaravelVuePagination from 'laravel-vue-pagination';
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css';
import router from './routes/index'

const app = createApp({

})
app.use(router)
app.use(VueSweetalert2)
app.component('Pagination', LaravelVuePagination)
app.mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

you should vuex for this perpose.

```
getUser(){
        axios.get('/api/user')
        .then(response => {
            this.$store.commit('storeUser',response)
            this.router.push({name: 'posts.index'})
        })
        
    },
```

**in store/index.js** (create folder of store in root )

```
    import { createApp } from 'vue'
    import { createStore } from 'vuex'
    
    // Create a new store instance.
    const store = createStore({
      state () {
        return {
          userData:{}
        }
      },
      getters: {
       userData(state){
        return state.userData
       }
      },
      mutations: {
        storeUser (state,payload) {
            state.userData= payload
        }
      }
    })
    
    export default store
```

**in main.js**

```
import store from 'store/index.js'
const app = createApp({ /* your root component */ })

// Install the store instance as a plugin
app.use(store)
```

in Authenticated.vue (or whereevet you want to use any value from store)

```
computed:{
    userData(){
      return this.$store.getters.userData        // here you can get your 
                                                   response object from api 
                                                 which you call during login
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you! I will try and implement this tonight